# A list of Android APIs that require certain Android permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Is there a way to tell if a certain Android permission is required by which Android APIs? For example, which APIs will require the GET_TASKS or REBOOT permissions? My app, inherited from someone who's long gone, has these permissions listed in the manifest. I don't think we are using them, but I'm also afraid that if I remove them, there will be bad consequences. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: If the project is not big. You can check it yourself. I think so... A good answer might not be existed.

Comment: 'afraid' does not belong here. You probably should try to achieve a good test coverage (preferably automatic testing) so then you remove or do whatever you want and if all the tests still pass then it's ok.

Comment: See this thread.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740632/mapping-between-android-permissions-that-we-define-in-the-manisfest-file-to-c/24019120#24019120][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740632/mapping-between-android-permissions-that-we-define-in-the-manisfest-file-to-c/24019120#24019120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of these permissions are quite specialized, and only have a few uses.

**android.permission.REBOOT**

First of all, this permission has a protection level of `signatureOrSystem`, so unless your application is part of a custom ROM or you have access to the signing keys for the platform you are installing it on, the application won't even be granted the permission.]

It is required to call `PowerManager.reboot()`

**android.permission.GET_TASKS**

This permission is only marked `dangerous`, so your app can actually obtain this one.

There are two calls in `ActivityManager` that require this permission, `getRecentTasks()` and `getRunningTasks()` to get information about the current application tasks in the system.  It's often used by custom Launcher applications to populate task lists.

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Is there an official doc that publishes such info, or is this insider knowledge?

Comment: If a particular API requires a given permission, it will say so in the SDK docs, so that's just running a search on the SDK docs for the permission names.  The security level you can find in the AndroidManifest.xml of the framework sources.

Answer (score 2):

PScout was a tool that analysed Android SDK and generated a map that maps Android permissions to methods that require those permissions.

Original PScout website doesn't work anymore but I extracted the mapping from original PScout and pushed it to Github. You can easily check it out and parse it if you need it.

Here you can find all methods that PScout found which require Android permissions.

[PScout results- map of Android permissions and methods that require those permissions](https://github.com/drag0/pscout_results)

Answer (score 0):

Take out each piece then run in. If it continues to work keep what is deleted and move down the list of permissions.